# React Bootstrap: How can I change the icon of Dropdown.Toggle from the arrow icon to some other icons from React Icon?

Tags: reactjs, icons, react-bootstrap

https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/components/dropdowns/#dropdown-toggle-props

This code will give us the toggle with an arrow:

```
<Dropdown.Toggle split variant="success" id="dropdown-split-basic" />
```

[image]

But I want to change the icon to other icons from react icon. I would appreciate it if someone can show me how. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add the following CSS to hide the default caret icon:

```
.dropdown-toggle::after {
  display: none;
}
```

Then when you define your dropdown, include the icon you want as part of your JSX:

```
<Dropdown>
  <Dropdown.Toggle variant="success" id="dropdown-basic">
    Dropdown Button
    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCaretSquareDown} style={{ marginLeft: '10px' }} />
  </Dropdown.Toggle>
  ...
</Dropdown>
```

In this case I've used a [Font Awesome](https://fontawesome.com/) icon, so have had to add the following dependencies to package.json:

```
"@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "1.2.36",
"@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "5.15.4",
"@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "0.1.16",
```

and the following imports to my component file:

```
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { faCaretSquareDown } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
```

The result is:

[image]

A working demo can be found [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/using-react-bootstrap-in-react-app-fqktwl?file=index.js).

Comment: works after adding !important, as:
    display: none !important;